# Using double pointers with const

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

Suppose we have

```
int *p1;
const int **pp2= &p1;
const int n=13;
```

// Which means we can't use pp2 to modify the value of the //variable whose address is stored in * pp2.
* pp2 stores the address of some variable (n in this case below)

The book which I am reading -C++ primer says the following statement is perfectly legal

```
*pp2=&n;
```

I feel the above statement violates the matter written in comments above.

Could somebody please help clear this. Thanks a lot

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/what-is-the-difference-between-const-int-const-int-const-and-int-const) for extensive discussion on the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps to understand it with a simple example. When you write the declaration below:

```
const int *p;
```

It says `*p` is constant not `p`. `p` can store any address pointing to constant integer.

Similarly `const int **p;` says pointer to pointer to a constant int. You can change `p` and `*p` but not `**p`. `*p` can hold any address pointing to constant integer like `&n` in your case and you can change `*P` with any addresses pointing to constant integer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Explains it very well.

Answer (score 3):

The type of `&n` is `int const *`.
The type of `*pp2` is `int const *`.

The `const` qualifies the pointee, not the pointer, in this case.

So assigning one to the other is perfectly valid. The comment you quoted may be wrong, and should perhaps say:

```
// Which means we can't use **pp2 to modify the value of the
// variable whose address is stored in *pp2.
```

---

To elaborate :

```
int *p1;
```

The above creates a variable named `p1` that can store the address of an `int`. It's type is `int*`. This statement doesn't initialize it, and so it hold an unspecified address (the value *it* can hold).

```
const int **pp2= &p1;
```

The above attempts to create and assign to a variable name `pp2`. It's type is `int const **` and the statement tries to assign it the address of `p1`. Now the expression `&p1` has the type `int **`, and the assignment fails, since the `const` qualifications mismatch.

---

As you can see, the code is in complete alignment with the (possibly corrected) statements.

Comment: Edited. Thank you for your answer. Could you please clarify a bit more. I am new to cpp. Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

First, please pay attention that your example code, by itself, cannot compile (at least in the compiler I am using), as the line `const int **pp2= &p1;` tries to assign an `int **` to a `const int **` - take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390294/conversion-from-int-to-const-int).

I believe that reading that page will help you understanding the problem you face either.