# Opposite of const_cast

Tags: c++

I have an `std::vector<int*> v` and I'd like to prevent further writes to it. The C++ compiler does not accept this

```
const std::vector<const int*>& w = v;
```

but it accepts this

```
const std::vector<const int*>& w = reinterpret_cast<const std::vector<const int*>&>(v);
```

The latter does work with Microsoft's compiler, meaning that the `int*` inside `v` and `const int*` inside `w` have the same addresses in memory.

Does this work by chance, as an unspecified behavior, or is it valid C++ ? Does it work with all types inside the vector, like `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>>` ? If invalid, is there another way to do this cast ?

I know I could also copy the vector, but I'd like to avoid that, since my vectors are pretty big.

Comment: What about declaring the vector as const: `const std::vector<int*> v;`?

Comment: @vahancho The problem is the `const int*`, not the `const vector`.

Comment: So, you want to prevent rather the modification of **elements** than modification of vector itself?

Comment: @vahancho I want to prevent both kinds of writes, yes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122858/why-is-a-vector-of-pointers-not-castable-to-a-const-vector-of-const-pointers

Comment: Your `reinterpret_cast` is UB.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63422076/why-is-type-punning-considered-ub

Comment: [`std::experimental::propage_const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) might help.

Comment: Sounds like you should encapsulate it and enforce the `const` semantics you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is Undefined Behavior.

`std::vector<const int*>` and `std::vector<int*>` are two different classes (generated by the same template, but that is irrelevant). They cannot alias each other and you cannot `reinterpret_cast` between them.

My solution is to use [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span):

```
const std::span s{const_cast<const int* const*>(v.data()), v.size()};
```

This will create a `const std::span<const int* const>`.

Comment: This is certainly an elegant solution. The `const_cast` makes it somewhat ugly though. It'd be better if we could get rid of that.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili yes, there is a way nicer solution: to modify the original variable type. Since that is not possible for OP I feel this is the next best thing. The `const_cast` is not a problem for me because it is used to add const, not remove it.

Comment: I cannot change the type of the variable, because the vector really is modified up to a certain point in the algorithm, and then it becomes read-only and used as input for the rest of the algorithm. I am in C++14 so I cannot use span, but exposing const getters to the beginning and end of the vector should be enough. Thanks.

Comment: @bolov do note that adding const like that _is_ dangerous. See [Conversion from int** to const int**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16390294/10147399). Or else the conversion would have been implicit.

Comment: @Artyer oh wow, I was so wrong. Thank you for pointing it out. Edited.